# How do I use Ctrl + Fn + Num on XFCE

Tags: arch-linux, xfce

On Gnome, using Tweak Tool under typing, I set the numeric keypad keys on my laptop to work as numbers only on pressing Fn + key not when I turn the numlock on. See below. I use it mainly in Libreoffice to set the styles with Ctrl + Fn + 1 for Header 1, etc.
At present on XFCE pressing

- Ctrl + Fn + 1 (physical key j) is interpreted as the "End" key.
- Ctrl + Shift + Fn + 1 gives nothing
- but Shift + Fn + 1 gives "1".

[image]
This is because my laptop does not have a proper keypad. The numeric keypad uses the normal letter keys on the right.

How do I achieve the same effect on XFCE? Is there a way to make XFCE use Ctrl + Fn + Num combinations?

Comment: As far as I know the `Fn` key is not serviced by the `OS` - it is implemented in hardware, so I am surprised that you have it working with Gnome and not working with XFCE

Comment: The Gnome XKB setting was with the Numlock key not the Fn keys.

Comment: How did you do it in Gnome? The underlying mechanism doesn't depend on the desktop environment. If there's a Gnome user interface for it, figure out what command (probably XKB-related) it emits under the hood, and call that. If you need help figuring it out, tell us how you did it in Gnome.

Comment: In the Question body you use `Fn + Num` and `Fn + key` (singular) .in the comment above `Fn keys` (plural). Could you be more specific, please

Comment: Added an image to clarify how I achieved the right configuration.

Comment: Maybe the problem is not the keyboard configuration but XFCE recognising Ctrl + Fn + Key combinations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer myself with the help of another similar answer.

Go to `Settings`, `Settings Editor`, `keyboard-layout` and under XkbOptions, I added `numpad:microsoft` to the Group string.

Now it's working as it used to do in Gnome.